# Running TestCases (from Maven) when TestCases are in src?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that itself is a set of test cases for an application. The test cases are tested itself using a mockup of the application to ensure the tests itself is correct. This is important to ensure the test cases justify some sort of specifications that are hard to follow and easy to mess up.

Now I want the final tests (those who are tested before) being in src in Maven. As expected mvn test just executes the test cases of the test cases not the test cases themself.

So basically how do I execute test cases that reside inside the 'src' folder using a maven goal?

Comment: What is your question

Comment: in test folder there are tests that test the test cases. The problem is that this is a test project containing the acceptance tests of an application developed by another team. So basically the acceptance tests are tested to enforce the specification correctly and are ment to run independently testing an application in black box mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>
```